# Reference style

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have to use reference styling adopted by elsevier, in which references are quoted like this in latex:

```
Rukhin et al. (2010), Godbole and Papastavridis (1994)
```

I put the `elsarticle-num.bst` and `model4-names.bst` in my folder in which all other latex files of my document are present.

I have put this code in the end of the document:

```
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{referencess}
\nocite{*}
```

I am referring to the references like this

```
\cite{1}
```

but reference does not appear like this

```
 Rukhin et al. (2010)
```

What can be the possible reason?

Comment: You need to use `\cite{key}` where key is the key for your bib entry. Look into your bibliography file. The entry starts like `@book{KEY, .....}`. That's the key you need.

Comment: In the `references.bib` file, the paper by Rukhin and others will start with something like `@article{rukhin2010,` (`@article` could be some other type and the string might be different); you should use `\cite{rukhin2010}` (with the actual string, of course).

Comment: @egreg I tried that as well but when I compile it on winedit it still gives [1].

Comment: Do you have `\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}`? Maybe with other options, but `authoryear` is necessary to have an author-year citation style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want authoryear-style (aka "Harvard-style") instead of numeric-style citation callouts for an Elsevier-stable journal, you should use the instruction

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

Because you're dealing with the `elsarticle` document class, you should load it with the options `natbib` and `authoryear` to complete the process of getting authoryear-style citation callouts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[natbib,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{runs94,
  title    = "Runs and Patterns in Probability: Selected Papers",
  editor   = "Godbole, Anant P. and Papastavridis, Stavros G.",
  year     = 1994,
  series   = "Mathematics and Its Applications",
  number   = 233,
  publisher= "Springer",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\citet{runs94}

\section*{References}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run Latex command it gives me an error : Latex Error: file "Image" not found. However, when I just compile it without running Latex, no such error appears and latex file appears.

Comment: It is a pdf file having an image. I just changed the \bibliographystyle instruction. Which other instruction do I need to change?

Comment: @zara - I've completely updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use \bibliographystyle{plainnat} with \citet{yourreference}. You will get exactly what you want.

Comment: But will the references be formatted according to Elsevier guidelines if one uses a style file *other* than `elsarticle-num` or (as I advocate doing in my answer) `elsarticle-harv`?