# Bibtex-Natbib-Failure to change in-text citations from numerical style to "author-date" style

Tags: citing, natbib

I am having a difficulty inserting my references in the text in the "author-date" format. I have read all possible blogs and documents and haven't figured it out yet. I am new to this software, so maybe I am missing a key command/feature in order to make it work.

The following is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\biboptions{comma,round}
\begin{document}
[Manuscript text composed of different sections:Abstract, Introduction, Materials 
  and Methods, Results and Discussion, Conclusion and References; with in-text 
  citations in the following form: \cite{Menaa}]
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references-updated-send3}
\end{document}
```

If I write it in the following form:

\usepackage[comma,round]{natbib}

the latex document would not generate the PDF document

With all these commands in place, when I use natbib specific commands such as `\citep` or `\citet`, the in-text citations still appear in the numerical style.

I am not sure whether I should modify my bibtex style or something to appear in the latex document in the proper style. The one thing I know for sure, is that my bibtex is accessible because references are showing up within the text and in the references section, but those within the text are in the wrong format.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback as it will help me tremendously advance on my manuscript.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered specifying the option `authoryear` when loading `natbib`? (Be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.)

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks Mico, how do you specify the option author-year upon natbib loading? Christian, thanks for the feedback, I have edited my initial request by including information that would hopefully shed some light on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for modifying your posting and indicating that you use the `elsarticle` document class. This is a crucial piece of information. In this case, you need to write `\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}` to get authoryear-style citation callouts. Moreover, since you're using the `elsarticle` document class, you should probably use the bibliography style `elsarticle-harv` instead of `plainnat` to adhere to Elsevier's formatting guidelines. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193960/5001.

Comment: Mico, thank you very much for sharing your expertise. I followed your suggestions and it worked great! Thanks again. However, I have been running through some obstacles, for some of the references, the format within the text is in the wrong format, I tried changing bibtex information and insert the citation again, but it didn't work out. Is Bibtex automatically updated upon modification of its contents? Once updated, would it apply automatically in the text without having to update it manually? Again, I deeply appreciate your time and efforts!